# Asynchronous parallel web requests in ASP.NET MVC(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, httpwebrequest

I have a mini-project that requires to download html documents of multiple websites using C# and make it perform as fast as possible. In my scenario I might need to switch IP using proxies based on certain conditions. I want to take advantage of C# Asynchronous Tasks to make it execute as many requests as possible in order for the whole process to be fast and efficient.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
public class HTMLDownloader
{

    public static List<string> URL_LIST = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> HTML_DOCUMENTS = new List<string>();

    public static void Main()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < URL_LIST.Count; i++)
        {
            var html = Task.Run(() => Run(URL_LIST[i]));
            HTML_DOCUMENTS.Add(html.Result);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<string> Run(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        //Handle Proxy Credentials client.Proxy= new WebProxy();
        string html = "";
        try
        {
            html = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
            //if(condition ==true)
            //{
            //  return html;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //  Switch IP and try again
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return html;
    }
```

The problem here is that I'm not really taking advantage of sending multiple web requests because each request has to finish in order for the next one to begin. Is there a better approach to this? For example, send 10 web requests at a time and then send a new request when one of those requests is finished.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your question is ASP.NET related?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to take advantage of C# Asynchronous Tasks to make it execute as many requests as possible in order for the whole process to be fast and efficient.

You can use `Task.WhenAll` to get asynchronous concurrency.

> For example, send 10 web requests at a time and then send a new request when one of those requests is finished.

To *throttle* asynchronous concurrency, use `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
  using var limit = new SemaphoreSlim(10); // 10 at a time
  var tasks = URL_LIST.Select(Process).ToList();
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  HTML_DOCUMENTS.AddRange(results);

  async Task<string> Process(string url)
  {
    await limit.WaitAsync();
    try { return await Run(url); }
    finally { limit.Release(); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8).

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have
>   completed.

The premise is, `Select` all the tasks into a `List`, `await` the *list* of *task* with  `Task.WhenAll`, `Select` the results

```
public static async Task Main()
{
   var tasks = URL_LIST.Select(Run); 
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   var results = tasks.Select(x => x.Result);
}
```

<sub>Note : The result of `WhenAll` will be the collection of results as well</sub>

Comment: Good, but the `Select` at the end is an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 0):

First change your `Main` to be async.

Then you can use LINQ `Select` to run the `Tasks` in parallel.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var tasks = URL_LIST.Select(Run);

    string[] documents = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    HTML_DOCUMENTS.AddRange(documents);
}
```

`Task.WhenAll` will unwrap the `Task` results into an array, once all the tasks are complete.